# Warning:INFO: HHH000206: hibernate.properties not found

Tags: eclipse, hibernate

I want to insert the data in the database by using entity class and class given below,it is showing warning specifies above.How can I add data to database?

```
type herepackage org.studyeasy.Hibernate;

import org.hibernate.HibernateException;
import org.hibernate.Session;
import org.hibernate.SessionFactory;
import org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration;
import org.stusyeasy.Hibernate.entity.Users;

public class App {

    public static void main(String args[]) {
        
        try {
        Configuration  cfg = new Configuration().configure().addAnnotatedClass(Users.class);
        
        SessionFactory factory = cfg.buildSessionFactory();
        
        Session session = factory.getCurrentSession();
        //this will be connected to database
        
        try {
            //Step 1 : create and object based on entity class
            Users u1 = new Users(2,"Harshal","Hasrsh","Hasrshal","Takade");
            
             //Step 2 : Start transaction
            session.beginTransaction();
            
            //Step 3: Perform operation
            session.save(u1);
        //Step 4 : Commit Transaction
            session.getTransaction().commit();
            
        }
        finally {
            session.close();
            factory.close();
        }       
    }
        catch(HibernateException e) {
            
        }
    }
    
}
```

I placed the hibernate.cfg.xml file in the directory containing above class.How can I configure hibernate.properties file or hibernate.cfg.xml file in code ?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please take the [tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour) to learn how Stack Overflow works and read [How to Ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) or how to improve the quality of your question. Then edit your question to include log output [in text format](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/285557/5043481), not an image.
FInally please clearify the title. Is it a WARN or an INFO message?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: I want to configure hibernate properties,by which way I can do it?